# Python with Pandas TypeError: Super()

Tags: python, sql, pandas, typeerror, super

Python Newbie here.

I'm trying to pull a query using pandas module.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# Parameters
server = 'server'
db = 'Database'

# Create the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')

# query db
sql = """

SELECT DISTINCT fruits
FROM fruitstore

"""
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
df.head()
```

When I run this I end up with the error.

```
return super(IntervalDtype, cls).is_dtype(dtype)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I tried pinpointing the error myself, but I'm not getting anywhere. I know its not the DB or Server. Can anyone help me or at least give me some pointers on how I can figure out what this error is talking about.

I have a feeling its something simple I'm overlooking....

Anything helps.

Comment: I was getting the same error when reading CSV and Excel files with pandas. It isn't a solution per se, but in my case closing my IDE (Spyder for me) and opening it again solved the issue. 

According to the [links provided by komuw](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/144), this might because of an issue related to the `super()` class and [how modules are (re)loaded](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2011/09/382/). 

I can't really replicate the error. However, when testing, I tend to write and execute blocks of code in disorder, so I think it might have to do with that. HIH!